# Get current Frame from video_player plugin in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, video-player

Is there any method to get the current frame being played from the _controller or VideoPlayer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this package could be the answer https://pub.dev/packages/export_video_frame